# How to get ASCII characters out of hexadecimal values contained in a QString?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a *QString* containing multipe hexadecimal values from `0x00` to `0xFF`. 
I get the string from a *QTableWidget* and I want to convert the hex values in it to their corresponding ASCII characters, i.e. `0xAA` => `ª`, `0xFF` => `ÿ`, etc. The result should be displayed in a *QTextEdit*.

Here is a minimal excample:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QString asciiAsQString = "0x4A 0x3B 0x1F 0x0D";
    qDebug() << "hex as qstring." << asciiAsQString;
    QString f;

    for(int i = 0; i < asciiAsQString.length(); i++)
    {
        f.append(QChar(asciiAsQString.at(i).toLatin1()));
    }
    qDebug() << "ascii of hex contained in qString:" << f;
    return a.exec();
}
```

I have tried this and several similar things, but nothing works as I expect.

How can I fix the code to achieve the desired result?

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: Just to be precise: Be aware you are not operating on ASCII, but ISO latin 1; pure ASCII only uses the lower range of char ([0 .. 127]), anything above is non-ASCII. Luckily, ISO L1 is ASCII compatible on its lower range...

Comment: To clarify: your example contains a string with contents `'0', 'x', 'A', 'A', ' ', '0', 'x', ...`. Is that indeed what you receive?

Comment: Where do you want to show the symbols as : `ª`? in the console it will not be possible, do you want to show it in some widget? If so, what is that widget?

Comment: yes i want to show them in a simple textEdit widget

Comment: @Aconcagua i get the data as a Item from the tableWidget, them i convert them to a String: 
  `QString tmpMsgString = ui->canMsgWindow->item(row, 5)->text();`

Comment: *"containing multiple hexadecimal values"* - I assumed single characters are assigned such values. More precise wording can avoid such misunderstandings...

Comment: @eyllanesc, why do you say it's impossible to output the result to console?  My version works fine in console, in xterm and in Emacs compilation buffer.  Is there a reason you expect the output to fail somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something like

```
    QString asciiAsQString = "0x4A 0x3B 0x1F 0x0D";
    // You may need a bit of error checking to ensure the string is the right
    // format here.
    asciiAsQString.replace("0x", "").replace(" ","");  // Remove '0x' and ' '
    const QByteArray hex = asciiAsQString.toLatin1();
    const QByteArray chars = hex.fromHex();
    const QString text = chars.fromUtf8();
```

Depending on the encoding that the user is expected to enter, the last line should be `.fromLatin1()` or `.fromLocal8Bit()`.  I would encourage you to allow Utf8, because it allows the full range of Unicode.  It does mean ª would need to be entered as "C2 AA", but 提 can be entered as "E6 8F 90".

Comment: If input is all hexadecimal, why would one force the user to enter prefixes? Possibly, decimal values are allowed, too? Splitting the string and using strtoul with base 0 is might be a valuable alternative?

Comment: As user input involved, we *absolutely* need to validate, otherwise, we might end up in interpreting `0x123 456` as `0x12 0x34 0x56`...

Comment: @Aconcagua Why would one force the user to enter prefixes? Possibly because one didn't think very hard about the UI, and just thought "Oh, hex.  That must have a 0x prefix".  Yes, if you need to support both hex and decimal, then splitting, strtoul, and appending to QByteArray is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You could split on spaces, and convert each substring using `QString::toUShort()`, like this:

```
#include <QDebug>

int main()
{
    QString input = "0x61 43 0xaf 0x20 0x2192 32 0xAA";
    qDebug() << "Hex chars:" << input;

    QString output;

    for (auto const& s: input.split(' ', QString::SkipEmptyParts))
    {
        bool ok;
        auto n = s.toUShort(&ok, 0);
        if (!ok) {
            qWarning() << "Conversion failure:" << s;
        } else {
            output.append(QChar{n});
        }
    } 
    qDebug() << "As characters:" << qPrintable(output);
}
```

Output:

```
Hex chars: "0x61 43 0xaf 0x20 0x2192 32 0xAA"
As characters: a+¯ → ª
```